# Move windows-XP Pro from small C to a larger unallocated space on the same HDD?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

I still have lots of unallocated space at the end of my extended partition, but running short of space on the one and only primary partition  where C resides. It happens that beyond the extended partition is unallocated space much larger than the present C.  Rather than try merging extended partitions to get more space for C, is it simple to just create a new, larger, primary partition in the unallocated space, then move the the windows-XP Pro files to that larger primary?  Would the system startup OK if the boot up sequence is just pointed at the name of the new drive, or would it need to be renamed as C?  Is this the kind of move a novice could expect a disk cloning tool to do cleanly without a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest option would be to use [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to boot from then resize the partition.